# Override a custom property in a child view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a base view and a child view extending the base view with an attribute called "menu". I tried the following.

```
var baseView=Backbone.View.extend({
    menu:"#base-menu",
    initialize:function(){
         //some code
    },
    render:function(){
        console.log(this.menu);
    }
});
var childView=baseView.extend({
    initialize:function(){
        baseView.prototype.initialize.apply(this);
        this.menu="#child-menu";
    }
});
```

But the `childView.render()` does not output `#child-menu` it is only set to `#base-menu`. Why and how to get the child one set?

Note: there are multiple children views.

```js
var baseView = Backbone.View.extend({
  menu: "#base-menu",
  initialize: function() {
    console.log(this.menu);
  },

});

var firstView = baseView.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    baseView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    this.menu = "#child-menu";
    console.log(this.menu);

  }
});

var firstViewInstance = new firstView();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine (https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/hdc92byn/). Can you reproduce your problem? Are you really doing `childView.render()` rather than `c = new childView; c.render()`? Conventionally you'd have `BaseView` and `ChildView` as the "classes" and `childView` as an "instance" BTW.

Answer (score 1):

To override a property of a parent "class" with Backbone's `extend`, just set the property again:

```
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    menu: "#base-menu",
    initialize: function() {
        console.log("Base", this.menu);
    },

});

var ChildView =  BaseView.extend({
    menu: "#child-menu", // override directly here
    initialize : function(options) {
        ChildView.__super__.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log("Child", this.menu);
    }
});
```

Creating a child view:

```
var child = new ChildView();
```

Should output

```
Base #base-menu
Child #child-menu
```